# PHP require file back folder error file no found

Tags: php, xampp

[IDE File tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BmRyP.png)

Dears I´m having troubles in Xampp| W7.

I have this scructure folder in my IDE, but when I try to import a file in the root like 'require_once ('../php_conf.php')' only gives an error.

Xampp / php dont recognizes back navigation.

Any idea thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`../` uses your current working directory to resolve the path.

In order to check your current working directory you can use the command `getcwd()` ([php doc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php))

If you want to include a file which is in the parent directory even if your current working directory is different you can use `dirname()` ([doc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.dirname)) along with the [magic constant](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.magic.php) `__DIR__` which returns the directory of the current file.

```
require_once dirname(__DIR__) . '/php_conf.php'
```

You need to have appropriate permission for the file being imported.

Answer (score 0):

As per your IDE image you have `require_once ('..\php_conf.php');` Note the backslash.

If php_conf.php is at a folder one above the folder of current file, you can call it as below.

```
require_once ('../php_conf.php'); // use forward slash
```